# Likelihood ratio test vs p value for Poisson regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, p-value, likelihood, poisson-regression, likelihood-ratio

I have a Poisson regression model, from its summary table, I could see the p-value for a certain variable, e.g. gender. Since the p-value is testing the hypothesis whether the coefficient of gender equals to 0 (and it is comparing a model with all variables vs a model without this variable gender), seeing a p-value of 0.000 gives me the information that this variable is significant and should be included.   Now consider a likelihood ratio test where the null hypothesis is the reduced model without gender, and the alternative hypothesis is the full model with gender. From likelihood ratio test, if the p-value is small than a significance value, then we reject the null (reduced model), and therefore gender as a variable should be included.

I am a little bit confused about whether these two tests are equivalent in this scenario. Are they testing the same thing and will always produce same decision in this specific case? And if not, where are their differences?

Comment: It depends on which method your software uses to compute the p-value for gender: there are several options.  But ordinarily that test and the LR test give the same p-value (because often they are mathematically equivalent).  Have you, therefore, performed both tests on the same data and compared the results?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am using the R, no, the p-value is different in two cases

Comment: It would help to disclose the details.  There are many different ways to perform Poisson regression in `R`.

Comment: @whuber, I believe that it's true that "there are many different ways ...", but `glm()` would be the obvious one (and the only one built into base R ...??)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `glm()`, which is the standard/most-used tool for fitting Poisson regressions in R: the $p$-values in the table printed by `summary()` are so-called **Wald p-values**, which make a specific assumption about the sampling distribution of the parameter estimates (specifically that they are [multivariate] Normal, or equivalently that the log-likelihood surface is quadratic).  The $p$-values that you get from a likelihood ratio test (e.g., with `anova(full_model, restricted_model)` where `restricted_model` omits the focal parameter, or `drop1(full_model)`) also makes an assumption (that 2 x the log-likelihood difference between the models follows a chi-squared distribution when the null hypothesis is true), but the LRT assumption is much weaker than the one assumed by the Wald p-values, so the LRT $p$-values are in general more accurate.

As a side note, your statement that "... this variable is significant and should be included ..." makes me a bit nervous, as it suggests that you are using hypothesis testing to decide on the structure of your final model, which *may* be problematic (see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/2126)) ...

As an example from [UCLA OARC](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/poisson-regression/):

```r
p <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/poisson_sim.csv")
p <- within(p, {
  prog <- factor(prog, levels=1:3, labels=c("General", "Academic", 
                                                     "Vocational"))
  id <- factor(id)
})
m1 <- glm(num_awards ~ prog + math, family="poisson", data=p)
```

### Wald (summary())

```
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -5.24712    0.65845  -7.969 1.60e-15 ***
progAcademic    1.08386    0.35825   3.025  0.00248 ** 
progVocational  0.36981    0.44107   0.838  0.40179    
math            0.07015    0.01060   6.619 3.63e-11 ***
```

We get the same p-value for `math` (for example) using `aod::wald.test`:

```r
wald.test(b=coef(m1), Sigma=vcov(m1), Term=4)
Wald test:
----------

Chi-squared test:
X2 = 43.8, df = 1, P(> X2) = 3.6e-11
```

(The `X2` value is the square of the z-value listed in the `glm` summary)

### LRT (drop1)

```r
drop1(m1, test= "Chisq")
Single term deletions

Model:
num_awards ~ prog + math
       Df Deviance    AIC    LRT  Pr(>Chi)    
<none>      189.45 373.50                     
prog    2   204.02 384.08 14.572 0.0006852 ***
math    1   234.46 416.51 45.010  1.96e-11 ***
```

You'll note a few differences here ...

- for a categorical (factor) variable, `summary()` gives you a test for every level of the factor (except the baseline/first), representing differences between the baseline and other levels; `drop1()` gives you a single p-value for the combined effects (you can use `car::Anova()` to get a single Wald-based p-value per factor variable)
- for a numeric predictor, or a factor with only two levels (such as `gender` in most but not all cases), you'll get a single p-value either way, but they won't be identical. Both methods strongly reject the null hypothesis that there is no effect of `math`, but the p-values aren't the same (3.6e-11 for Wald and 1.96e-11 for LRT)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was wondering why the wald p-value is not the same as the p-value from the wald test. I saw there is the possibility to use wald.test(b=coef(model), Sigma=vcov(model), Terms=xx) in R. I used it to check about the p-value from the wald test (with the null hypothesis being that the coefficient of gender is zero), and it was different from the p-value for the covariate gender as shown in the GLM summary.

Comment: Yes, I am using wald.test from aod. I specified term as the location of the covariate in the model (e.g. Terms=2 since the covariate gender is the first covariate after intercept in my model).

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional example above! I just realized that it was only a rounding issue which led to me seeing 2 different p-values. Sorry for my confusion :)